# Object level permissions in Django admin

Tags: python, django, django-models, django-guardian

I have a model which looks like this:

```
class Change(models.Model):
    RFC = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    Ticket_Number = models.CharField(max_length=10)
    Plan_Owner = models.ForeignKey(User)
```

I then register the model in the Django admin via this:

```
class ChangeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    search_fields = ('RFC', 'Ticket_Number','Plan_Owner')
    list_display = ('RFC', 'Ticket_Number','Plan_Owner')

    fieldsets = [
        ('Ticket Details', {
            'fields': ['RFC', 'Ticket_Number', 'Plan_Owner']}),
    ]

admin.site.register(Change, ChangeAdmin)
```

What I want to achieve is to ensure that the Plan_owner for a particular change is the only one who can edit it apart from a superuser. Everyone can view it, but the plan owner is the only one who can make changes to it.Also by editing I mean, he can do ever thing but delete a row. I have had a look at Django guardian and it does exactly what I want but one has to manually set the permissions in guardian for each row. I am looking for a solution wherein these permissions are automatically set as per my requirements ...

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I wouldn't use object-level permission for something as simple as your requirement. You just need to have an `owner` ForeignKey to your Model and only allow the owner of each object to modify it (you can use the `Plan_Owner` -- *PLEASE change it to `plan_owner` and `Ticket_Number` to `ticket_number` to be compatible with pep 8 and  [django style guide](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/dev/internals/contributing/writing-code/coding-style/)*).

I have written a post that describes how to do this in django:

http://spapas.github.io/2013/11/05/django-authoritiy-data/

Actually I am describing how to use authorities that users belong to and each user can edit the objects of his authority but your requirement is covered.

**Update**

For completeness, I am adding the implementation here:

Your Create and Update Class Based Views have to pass the request to your forms and also your Detail and Update CBV should allow only getting objects that belong to the user (let's suppose that your model is named `UserData`:

```
class UserDataCreateView(CreateView):
  model=models.UserData

  def get_form_kwargs(self):
      kwargs = super(UserDataCreateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
      kwargs.update({'request': self.request})
      return kwargs

class UserDataDetailView(DetailView):
  def get_object(self, queryset=None):
      obj = super(UserDataDetailView, self).get_object(queryset)
      if not user_has_access(obj, self.request):
          raise Http404(u"Access Denied")
      return obj

class UserDataUpdateView(UpdateView):
  model=models.AuthorityData

  def get_form_kwargs(self):
      kwargs = super(UserDataUpdateView, self).get_form_kwargs()
      kwargs.update({'request': self.request})
      return kwargs

  def get_object(self, queryset=None):
      obj = super(UserDataUpdateView, self).get_object(queryset)
      if not user_has_access(obj, self.request):
          raise Http404(u"Access Denied")
      return obj
```

It checks if the `request.user` has permission (is the owner of the object) and also passes the `request` to the `ModelForm`. The `has_access` function defined above just checks if the current user is the owner of the object:

```
def has_access(obj, req):
    if req.user == obj.owner:
        return True
    return False
```

Yot ModelForm should be like this (same for create/update):

```
class UserDataModelForm(forms.ModelForm):
    class Meta:
      model = models.UserData
      exclude = ('owner',)

    def __init__(self, *args, **kwargs):
      self.request = kwargs.pop('request', None)
      super(ActionModelForm, self).__init__(*args, **kwargs)

    def save(self, force_insert=False, force_update=False, commit=True):
      obj = super(UserDataModelForm, self).save(commit=False)
      if obj:
          obj.owner = self.request.user
          obj.save()
      return obj
```

It removes `request` from `kwargs` and sets it as an attribute and at save it sets the owner of the object to the `reqest.user`.

Comment: Serafeim...i get a error in my admin.py saying :                   Exception Type: TypeError
Exception Value: 'tuple' object is not callable when i execute the code as per the initial question that I had posted ?                                                            How do I ensure that all the users come in a drop down menu in the django admin within the change model?

Comment: Hello  Amistad, in the propsed solution you will create your own views for adding / modifying objects and the admin interface will ``only`` be usable from Administrators that have access to all objects ! If you want to have user-owned objects also in your admin panel then you should ask it in a different question (however this is more difficult and not actually proposed since the admin interface should be visible only from admins and not normal users).

Answer (score 8):

You can easily do this by overriding the [get_queryset()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_queryset) of [ModelAdmin](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/contrib/admin/#django.contrib.admin.ModelAdmin) class. So [get_queryset()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_queryset) is the place where querying all the objects to display in the Admin Site. For example if you return `Change.objects.all()` in [get_queryset()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_queryset), will display all the objects in you `Change` model in Admin Site. If you return `Change.objects.none()` in [get_queryset()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_queryset), will not display any values in `Change` model in Admin Site.

This is what documentation mention about [get_queryset()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_queryset).

> Returns the queryset that will be used to retrieve the object that this view will display. By default, get_queryset() returns the value of the [queryset](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.queryset) attribute if it is set, otherwise it constructs a [QuerySet](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/models/querysets/#django.db.models.query.QuerySet) by calling the all() method on the [model](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.model) attribute’s default manager.

I just override [get_queryset()](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.2/ref/class-based-views/mixins-single-object/#django.views.generic.detail.SingleObjectMixin.get_queryset) in your `ChangeAdmin` class.

```py
class ChangeAdmin(admin.ModelAdmin):
    model = Change
    search_fields = ('RFC', 'Ticket_Number','Plan_Owner')
    list_display = ('RFC', 'Ticket_Number','Plan_Owner')

        fieldsets = [
        (
            'Ticket Details', {
                'fields': ['RFC', 'Ticket_Number', 'Plan_Owner']
            }
        ),
    ]

    def get_queryset(self, request):
        if request.user.is_superuser:
            return Change.objects.all()
        
        try:
            return Change.objects.filter(plan_owner_id=request.user.id)
        except:
            return Change.objects.none()


admin.site.register(Change, ChangeAdmin)
```

According to this example, if the superusers logged into the admin site they will see all the objects in the `Change` model. If other users who are in the `Change` table will display their own objects (because in this example, it's filter from according to the `Plan_Owner` of `Change` model), otherwise nothing display in Admin Site.